# How can I filter an array of objects by data from another array of objects?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Please, help to understand how realize this:

```
var filterAarray = [
  { id: 1, key: "fruits" },
  { id: 2, key: "fruits" },
  { id: 4, key: "vegetables" },
];

var foodArray = [
  {
    fruits: [
      { id: 1, label: "Apple" },
      { id: 2, label: "Cherry" }
    ],
    vegetables: [
      { id: 4, label: "Cucumber" }
    ]
  },
  {
    fruits: [
      { id: 1, label: "Apple" },
      { id: 2, label: "Cherry" },
      { id: 3, label: "Strawberry" }
    ],
    vegetables: [
      { id: 4, label: "Cucumber" },
      { id: 5, label: "Tomato" }
    ]
  }, {
    fruits: [
      { id: 2, label: "Cherry" },
    ],
    vegetables: [
      { id: 5, label: "Tomato" }
    ]
  }
];
```

I need to get filtered array of objects foodArray, that contains all data from the filterAarray.
The result must be:

```
[
  {
    fruits: [
      { id: 1, label: "Apple" },
      { id: 2, label: "Cherry" }
    ],
    vegetables: [
      { id: 4, label: "Cucumber" }
    ]
  },
  {
    fruits: [
      { id: 1, label: "Apple" },
      { id: 2, label: "Cherry" },
      { id: 3, label: "Strawberry" }
    ],
    vegetables: [
      { id: 4, label: "Cucumber" },
      { id: 5, label: "Tomato" }
    ]
  }
];
```

i.e. if objects of 'foodArray' are present in array 'filterAarray', then they must be shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```js
foodArray.filter(obj =>
    filterArray.every(e => !!obj[e.key].find(unit => unit.id === e.id)),
  );
```

General idea: check every object in `foodArray`. Then check if **every** element from `filterArray` is **found** in the array by `key`.

Take a look at:
[Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
[Array.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)
[Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)